# how to use -ms-filter inside jquery animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

i need to optimize my site for IE8. And it does not support opacity directly. It can be set using -ms-filter property. In my javascript am changing the opacity using jquery animate(). but how do i use it with -ms-filter

currently am giving this

```
$('.topbar img').animate({opacity:1, -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)"},1500);
```

but its throwing a JS error. Invalid property obviously. Can anybody help me how to animate in IE8..? Help appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552020/jquery-animating-opacity-in-ie

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try using:

```
$('.topbar img').animate(
      {
       opacity:1, 
       '-ms-filter': 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)'
//     ^quotes
      }
  ,1500);
```

[**See also...**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594117/ie9-why-setting-ms-transform-works-from-css-but-not-with-jquery-css/5594170#5594170)

Actually, using jquery, you shouldn't need the `-ms-filter` property. See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/hrNZF/) for an example

Comment: Thanks.. it worked partially... Its changing the opacity. But not animating. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery have a [step() callback](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) that gets triggered in every step of the animation.

```
$('.topbar img').animate({
  opacity: 1
},
{
  step: function(now, fx) {
    // Every step of the opacity animation we'll get the current 
    // opacity as the 'now' argument.
    var opacity = Math.round(now * 100);
    $(fx.elem).css('-ms-filter', 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=' + opacity + ')');
  }
});
```